# Android XmlPullParser whitespace hack. How would I do this more elegantly?

Tags: android, xmlpullparser, android-xmlpullparser

I have some XML in an Android application where XmlPullParser is the recommended solution for binding that XML to data model classes.  The Android documentation for XmlPullParser is fairly good except for how to deal with inter element whitespace.  The recommended approach is to detect low-level  IGNORABLE_WHITESPACE parsing events and skip over those events.  However for the XML I am trying to accept, this approach is not working for me.  I never see the low level IGNORABLE_WHITESPACE events occurring.  Which has me believing that I do not correctly understand some aspect of my particular use case, either XmlPullParser behavior, acceptable XML, or possibly a configuration issue.

My simplified test case for an XML snippet that I am trying to accept is:

```
<a>  <b></b>  </a>
```

and the code hack I am using to accept this element with the recommended getNextToken() method is:

```
            boolean hasEvent = false;
            String desc = null;
            while (!hasEvent) {
                result = xpp.nextToken();
                desc = xpp.getPositionDescription();
                Log.i(TAG, String.format("Processing: %s", desc));
                switch (result) {
                case START_TAG:
                case END_TAG:
                case END_DOCUMENT:
                    hasEvent = true;
                    break;

                case TEXT:
                    // Use a real hack to detect whitespace.
                    if (desc.contains("TEXT (whitespace)@")) {
                        hasEvent = false;
                    } else {
                        hasEvent = true;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
```

and the result that I see is, essentially: got START_TAG(a), got TEXT (whitespace), got START_TAG(b), got END_TAG(b), got TEXT (whitespace), got END_TAG(a).

So the questions are: what am I not understanding correctly?  And how would I accept this sequence without resorting to an ugly hack, something more in keeping with recommended use of XmlPullParser.

I have a hunch that this is questionable XML but it is representative of what I will be presented with, i.e. I cannot control the inter-element whitespace in the input stream.

fwiw, the Simple Framework for XML deals with this input stream without a hiccup and is my preferred approach but that package is very, very messy to use with Gradle and Android Studio due to dependency conflicts with the underlying stax and epp libraries, but that is another issue entirely.

Answer (score 0):

To somewhat answer my own question, I offer up the following for developers who find themselves in my situation at some point.  But I very much look forward to even better answers soon.

As for lack of understanding, the first point is that now I understand that I am using a non validating parser.  This claim is made in the Android XmlPullParser source code/Javadoc for isWhitespace():

> Please note: non-validating parsers are not able to distinguish whitespace and ignorable whitespace, except from whitespace outside the root element. Ignorable whitespace is reported as separate event, which is exposed via nextToken only.

This leads me to believe that JAXB and Simple are validating parsers and can deal with this inter-element whitespace in stride whereas I now must deal with it explicitly, much to my chagrin.

A second point that falls under the lack of understanding umbrella is that Android's XmlPullParser can only create validating parsers by providing a "schema" to back the validation, something that is pretty much out of my control for this instance.

As for a more elegant way to deal with inter-element whitespace, my answer would be to have two methods: getNextElement() which will return the next START_TAG or END_TAG event but throw away all TEXT events where the text is whitespace, anything else is deemed a parsing error; the other method would be getNextText() which will return text from either TEXT or CDSECT parsing events and report any other event as an error.

As I said, I'm looking forward to better answers.